# getting everyhing until dollar sign, but also if no dollar sign present

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to get everyhing until the dollar sign, like that :

```
$$uhttp:///www.stackoverflow.com$$3blablabla
```

`sed -r 's/\$\$u(http.*)(\$\$.*)/\1/g' thefile`

That give me the link.

But if I only have this :

$$uhttp:///www.stackoverflow.com

The same sed won't work.

Making the last part optional, with "*" (zero or more), does not work :

`sed -r 's/\$\$u(http.*)(\$\$.*)*/\1/g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is failing because you require the second set of dollar signs to match. Try this: match "http" followed by one or more *non-dollar characters*.

```
sed -r 's/\$\$u(http[^$]+).*/\1/' thefile
```

Or, even simpler

```
grep -Eo 'http[^$]+' thefile
```

Comment: Great !   Those 2 works ! Thanks.    Better than what I came up with :  `sed -r 's/\$\$u(http.*)(\$\$.*|$)/\1/g'`,  that is asking for "$$", or the end of line.